# Checking value in database in two columns

Tags: java, mysql

I have a MySQL table with columns like id and name. I just want to take a value in a variable sometimes id and sometimes name.  How do I check a value in two columns?

I have tried something like this:

```
select count(*) from topic where (name= '"+ name + "' or id='"+name+"')
```

The variable name is the same, so I have to check in two columns.

Comment: which programing  language you used like java,php?

Comment: java..................

Comment: do you have the name/id variable in java before calling mysql, are you creating the sql strings programatically? one word answers are of limited use.

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Comment: @user1891823: if `id` is int then how can u match with `name` string field? Your question has no clear meaning..

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `LIKE` instead of `=`

Comment: the query itself is fine (provided that you use quotes correctly). What behavior are you expecting? It should return the number of rows that have `name` in either the `id` or the `name`column. What are you retrieving instead?

Comment: I just want to know the whether this name and id is present in the table or not

Comment: in that case the semantics of the original posting are correct

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to add the values you would like in your `SELECT` clause.

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) count, name, id
FROM topic
WHERE (name= '"+ name + "' or id='"+name+"')
```

Comment: the problem is we dont know what you really want, the above is correct SQL for finding the number of rows where either the name column is exactly equal to name or the id column is exactly equal to name.

Comment: ya same thing i want but count is zero only,while value is already present in table

Comment: maybe you could give us some example rows from your table?

Answer (score 0):

What is the data type of ID. If it is an int then you don't need the single quotes around id. Also you don't need the parentheses in your statement. And you must enclose everything in double quotes if this statement is inside a Java program.

Jason Posit

Comment: @user1891823: if `id` is int then how can u match with `name` string field? Your question has no clear meaning...

Comment: see i have  string type  name variable, in this variable value is coming from textbox from other page,and this value is sometimes id(integer type) and sometimes name(String type), and I have to check in the table wethere this value is present or not... now i think u ll get....

Answer (score 0):

in the case you're checking for name you want this:

```
    select count(*) from topic where (name= '"+ name + "');
```

in the case you're checking for id you want this:

```
    select count(*) from topic where (id= '"+ name + "');
```

then you want to use a "case when statement" like so:
first define

```
    column_to_match to be = 'name' or = 'id' depending on your scenario
```

then

```
    select count(*) from topic where (case column_to_match when 'name' then name= '"+ name + "' when 'id' then id= '"+ name + "' end case);
```

i recommend you rename the name variable to something like val

Comment: in same variable sometimes i am getting name and sometimes getting id. I Didnt get ur example...

Comment: ok but do you know what you're getting? if not then how are we to know... what is the schema - could someone's name be 12345 - we need more info

Comment: SQL needs to be told whether were in the name case or the id case, you cant just have a variable hold either and expect the computer to work it out.. there must be some logic and that is what i mean by setting column_to_match... depending on your scenario

Comment: i dont know what is in variable whether it is id or name , how can i make the  case....